# Updating folder name via google drive api v3

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to update folder name in google drive api v3
the api am using is

https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/

Am passing the above url in mule4 application in a http connector

using below request body

```
{
"name":"Job_08_2020",
"mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
"parents":["parentId"]
}
```

using patch method but am getting error as method not allowed. Any ways to achieve this?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.  We need to see the request you are making and the full error message.

Comment: Why are you specifying the mimeType? Are you trying to change it? Which error exactly are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Android Method    
fun getDriveService(): Drive? {
            GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context)?.let { googleAccount ->
                val credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    context, listOf(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)
                )
                credential.selectedAccount = googleAccount.account
                return Drive.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
                    credential
                )
                    .setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .build()
            }
    
            return null
        }
    
        fun updateGoogleDriveFolderName(name: String, googleDrive: Drive?, folderId: String) {
            googleDrive?.let { google ->
                val googlefile = com.google.api.services.drive.model.File()
                googlefile.name = name
                google.files().update(folderId, googlefile).execute()
            }
```